# Error in connecting Database(MongoDB) with express server

Tags: node.js

As soon as I am connecting my database with express using

```
const db = require("./config/mongoose");
```

It shows error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Vs Code Folders\Feelare\node_modules\whatwg-url\lib\url-state-machine.js:8:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can I get out of it?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally comes when you do not provide valid JSON data.

For ex:-

```
JSON.stringify({x:})
```

return error like this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

Please check your provided JSON data again.

And after that you still get error please show your `mongoose` connection code.

Comment: I have checked my code but their is not JSON error. This my mongoose .js code               
 `const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/feelare_db');

const db = mongoose.connection ;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "Error in connecting to MongoDB "));

db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connected to Database:: MongoDB');
})

module.exports = db;`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine. I have not got any error. I got successful connection message in console `Connected to Database:: MongoDB`.

**Try this code it will also work for you.**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/feelare_db");
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Error in connecting to MongoDB "));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected to Database:: MongoDB");
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: I'm getting same error @HarshMangalam

Comment: I have tried with your code and imported as                                                                                                ` const db = require("./config/mongoose"); `                                                                                                                     and I'm getting same error as above `@HarshMangalam`

Comment: I have tried `const db = require("./config/mongoose"); console.log(db);` it works and console `<ref *1> NativeConnection {
  base: Mongoose {
    connections: [ [Circular *1] ],
    models: {},
    events: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    options: {
      pluralization: true,
      aut`

Comment: Yeah, Now it's working , I have also made couple of more changes in my code .                                    Thanks!!`@HarshMangalam`

Comment: @AasthaGoyal good job